# Rails: rendering collection of different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have defined a `@results` variable in my controller that contains different models and want to render them in my view using `<%= render @results` %>.

How can I give the `render` method the address for the directory that contains the partials for these models.

**Solution**

```
<% @results.each do |result| %>
      <%= render "home/partials/#{result.class.name.downcase}", result.class.name.downcase.to_sym => result%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Anyone want to comment as to why they're down-voting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render will look in the current object's view directory:

```
render 'form' # renders _form.html.erb in same directory
```

To look in another directory, add it's directory name:

```
render 'shared/form' # renders _form.html.erb in views/shared/
```

Since your results variable apparently contains multiple models, just assign a `directory` value to each entry in the hash or array and call it in the view or controller.

That's the best I can give you based on the very, very little information in your question.

Comment: Thanks. I called `each` on results and gave the partial address dynamically. imo I think I provided enough info in the question. I'd upvote but the down-votes cost me my up-vote privileges :).